# How to correct "Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field" when restoring a PHPMyAdmin backup?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, database-restore

I have a few databases that use POINT fields in MySQL to store geometry data. All the data is added in the same way:

```
GeomFromText( 'POINT( lat lng )' )
```

All the databases backup and restore without problems except for one. This database is on the same server as the others, but in a separate CPanel account.

When I try to restore that database, I get this error:
"Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field"

An example of the insert statement is:

```
INSERT INTO `location` (`id`, `coords` , `new_coords`) VALUES
(1, '\0\0\0\0\0\0�a��[XJ@�˶x��', '\0\0\0\0\0\0�8z�%XJ@g�+����' ),
(3, '\0\0\0\0\0\0�n�w�/J@6���', '\0\0\0\0\0\0�n�w�/J@6���' ),
(4, '\0\0\0\0\0\0�  ��@J@.����', '\0\0\0\0\0\0� ��@J@.����');
```

I have checked the data and it all seems to show valid latitudes and longitudes when I run this query:

```
SELECT X( coords ) , Y( coords ) FROM location
```

A few of the records return 0 and 0. So I tried updating those to NULL and I still get the same error.

When I try to export with or without the "Dump binary columns in hexadecimal notation" option ticked, I also get the same error.

Is there a setting that can cause this issue or is it just going to be something in the data?

If it's the data, what would the fix be?

Thanks in advance :)

This is exporting from a Linux MariaDB server (10.1.37-MariaDB) on PHP 7.2.7 using PHPMyAdmin 4.8.3 and importing on to WAMPServer 3.1.4 (10.3.9-MariaDB) using PHP 7.2.10 using PHPMyAdmin 4.8.3.
Please note, this also did not work on WAMPServer 3.0.8

Comment: What mysql/mariaDB version is the backup from? and going to? What is the SQL statement from the backup causing the error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've added more details above. "From" MariaDB version: 10.1.37. "To" WAMPServer 3.1.4 (10.3.9-Maria DB). Also does not work on WAMPServer 3.0.8 which does not appear to use MariaDB. Example MySQL insert code is above.

Comment: Isn't there an option to export binary data in base64? It seems to me like encoding or misinterpretation issues. Maybe windows has problems with the 0 bytes.

Comment: There is the "Dump binary columns in hexadecimal notation", but it doesn't work with that turned on or turned off. I've resaved all the data and it works, I'll add a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for this, although it would be nice to find out what was causing the issue in the first place. I extracted the data from the database using PHP, then resaved it only using POINT() instead of using GeomFromText( 'POINT()' ).

1) Query the database for the data:

```
SELECT id , X( coords ) AS x , Y( coords) AS y FROM location
```

2) Loop through the rows and store the data in variables. Convert any empty lng/lat into 0:

```
$id = (int) $row['id'];
$x = ($row['x'] == "") ? 0 : $row['x'];
$y = ($row['y'] == "") ? 0 : $row['y'];
```

3) Update the data using POINT():

```
UPDATE location SET coords = POINT( ".$x." , ".$y." ) WHERE id = ".$id
```

4) Consider changing your insert code to use POINT() without any of the GeomFrom functions (GeomFromWKB/GeomFromText) if you are using MySQL 5.1.35 or later.

After that, your backup should be fine.

Comment: Thx for this question. I am running into the same problem, my CREATE table statement sets the location field as  POINT type, location` point DEFAULT NULL; and the insert statement passes  '\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\ÐoN\Ûu%º¿ 0žACÁI@'  as values. I am using mySQL Workbench v8.0

Comment: It's probably worth checking your storage engine and collation. For reference, I'm using InnoDB and latin1_swedish_ci.